# Import Data from .CSV TO SQL using FileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have an .CSV file which contain reviews and I am to programatically transfer the contents over into SQL Database from an FileUpload control. The problem I have is that my control are working but I dont see any data being populated in my database. Here is my code:

MarkUp

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"onclick="Button1_Click"                                                               Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>



Code Behind

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

            if (fileExt == ".csv")
            {
                OleDbConnection oconn = new     OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + FileUpload1 + ";     Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");

                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [AudioPR$]",     oconn);
                    oconn.Open();

                    OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
                    string Device = "";
                    string Source = "";
                    string Reviewer = "";
                    string Datetime = "";
                    string Links = "";
                    string Content = "";
                    string Subject = "";

                    while (odr.Read())
                    {

                        Device = valid(odr, 0);
                        Source = valid(odr, 1);
                        Reviewer = valid(odr, 2);
                        Datetime = valid(odr, 3);
                        Links = valid(odr, 4);
                        Content = valid(odr, 5);
                        Subject = valid(odr, 6);

                        InsertDataIntoSql(Device, Source, Reviewer, Datetime, Links,     Content, Subject);

                    }

                    oconn.Close();

                 }

                 catch (Exception ee)
                {
                    Label1.Text = ee.Message;
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Data Inserted Successfully";
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                }

            }

            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Only .csv files allowed!";

            }

        }

         else
            {

            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file!";

            }

       }



    protected string valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)

    {
        object val = myreader[stval];
        if (val != DBNull.Value)
        {

            return val.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToString(0);
        }


    }

    public void InsertDataIntoSql(string Device, string Source, string Reviewer, string     Datetime, string Links, string Content, string Subject)

    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CI0000000879107\\BENSON;    Initial Catalog=PRClips Mail;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AudioPR(Device, Source, Reviewer, Datetime,     Links, Content, Subject) VALUES(@Device, @Source, @Reviewer, @Datetime, @Links, @Content,     @Subject)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Device", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Device;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Source", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Source;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reviewer", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =     Reviewer;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Datetime", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = Datetime;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Links", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Links;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Content;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Subject;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

   }
}
```

I realize that having an connection is kinda pointless when I could just reading the contents from the FileUpload but if anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong or could guide to a proper direction that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time

Comment: It appears you want the SO community to do your debugging for you.  A better question would be _you_ finding problem area and providing us a small, concise program that reproduces your issue.

Comment: your right, i dont think i looked this through properly enough

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I figured it for those who were aiming for the same thing I was..couple things first

- I am importing a .CSV file, so your connection string is going to be different then most excel connection string
- Second, make sure you dispose your file cuz that gives you problems for file in use even though its closed, but it will crash if its open (I havent worked on that part of the code yet)
- Third, if your importing data to a database make sure your datatypes are right..for example, i had a lot of data coming and it was being traucated so i had to change my datatypes to proper format.

MarkUp:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
                       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Not much done here, just basic controls

C# Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)   //Upload file here
        {

            string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);  //Get extension

            if (fileExt == ".csv")   //check to see if its a .csv file
            {

                FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\FolderName\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);        //save file to the specified folder
                OleDbConnection oconn = new     OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\AudioPRFiles\\; Extended     Properties='text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited'");   //string connection for .CSV     OR Text file

                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" +     FileUpload1.FileName + "]", oconn);    //Select statement, if your using .CSV...put the name of the file NOT the excel tab


                oconn.Open();

                OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();  


                string Device = "";
                string Source = "";
                string Reviewer = "";
                string Datetime = "";
                string Links = "";
                string Content = "";
                string Subject = "";

                while(odr.Read())

                {

                    Device = valid(odr, 0);     //Call the valid method...see below
                    Source = valid(odr, 1);
                    Reviewer = valid(odr, 2);
                    Datetime = valid(odr, 3);
                    Links = valid(odr, 4);
                    Content = valid(odr, 5);
                    Subject = valid(odr, 6);

                    InsertDataIntoSql(Device, Source, Reviewer, Datetime, Links, Content, Subject);  //Call the InsertDataIntoSql method...see below

                    FileUpload1.Dispose();  //Dispose the file


                }

                oconn.Close();   //Close connection

            }

            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Label1.Text = ee.Message;
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            finally
            {
                Label1.Text = "Data Inserted Successfully";
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

            }

        }

        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Only .csv files allowed!";

        }

    }

    else
    {

        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file!";

    }    
 }



protected string valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)  //this method checks for null values in the .CSV file, if there are null replace them with 0

{
    object val = myreader[stval];
    if (val != DBNull.Value)
    {

        return val.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return Convert.ToString(0);
    }


}

public void InsertDataIntoSql(string Device, string Source, string Reviewer, string Datetime, string Links, string Content, string Subject) //method to insert data into database

{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerAddress; Database=MyDatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=True");                        //SQL connection
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();                           //SQL command
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "USE [MyDataBase] INSERT INTO Table_Name(Device, Source, Reviewer, Datetime, Links, Content, Subject) VALUES(@Device, @Source, @Reviewer, @Datetime, @Links, @Content, @Subject)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Device", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = Device;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Source", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Source;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reviewer", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Reviewer;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Datetime", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date).Value = Datetime;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Links", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Links;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Content;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subject", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Subject;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

   }
}

Hope this helps..Thanks
```